# в визуальном редакторе edit не отображается содержимое страницы

Tags: php, wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в админке захожу в страницы нажимаю "изменить" и не выдает страницу для редактирования а только название страницы и ...  хотя она существует в wp я новичке и был бы рад помощи.

Comment: На первом скрине и есть редактор. Бери и заполняй контентом

Comment: мне надо изменить контент страницы , она уже существует (2 скрин)

Comment: По всей видимости это самодельная тема для WoprdPress? Если так, то это в корне не верная посадка сайта на CMS а значит весь контент лежит в коде. Либо попробуйте установить плагин ClassicEditor возможно тема не поддерживает Gutenberg.

Comment: cспосибо большое мне помогло